# Conditions under which an Induced Representation is irreducible

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $$\eta_1,\eta_2,\eta_3, \dots \eta_n:\mathbb{F}_p^* \to \mathbb{C}^*$$ be the $1-$dimensional characters of multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$.

> Now consider the group of invertible matrices $G=GL_n({\mathbb{F}_p})$. Consider its subgroup $U$ of upper triangular matrices. Let $\overline{\eta}:U \to C^*$ to be the one-dimensional character defined by

$$\overline{\eta}\Big(\Bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
t_1 &  & *\\ 
  &\ddots  & \\ 
 0&  & t_n
\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr)\Big)=\eta_1(t_1)\eta_2(t_2)\eta_3(t_3) \dots \eta_n(t_n)
$$

> Under what conditions is the induced representation $\operatorname{Ind}^{G}_{U}$ irreducible?

Using Mackey's Irreducibility Criterion, I can conclude that $\overline{\eta}$ should be irreducible. But how can I simplify this further?

Comment: I am a little confused by which representation you used Mackey on. $\overline{\eta}$ is one-dimensional.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay, Since 1-dimensional representations are irreducible then it won't help. Then how should I proceed?

Comment: I am not actually sure what a good approach is. I only really know how this goes if you replace the finite field with its algebraic closure and replace the complex numbers by that as well. I think this is related to Deligne-Lusztig stuff, but it has been a while since I actually studied that.